# Partitioning a list on Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

How would i go about making a partition function that would take a number and a list to partition the list into smaller lists of lists whose size is given by the number
so that

```
Partition 3 '(a b c d e f g h) -> '((a b c) (d e f) (g h)) and etc. using take and drop?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you some hints so you can find the answer by yourself. Fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (partition n lst)
  (cond (<???>                      ; if the list is empty
         <???>)                     ; then return the empty list
        ((< <???> n)                ; if the lists' length is less than n
         <???>)                     ; return a list with lst as its only element
        (else                       ; otherwise
         (cons                      ; cons a list with the result of
          (<???> lst n)             ; grabbing the first n elements of lst with
          (<???> n                  ; the result of advancing the recursion and
                 (<???> lst n)))))) ; removing the first n elements of lst
```

Clearly, you'll have to use `take` and `drop` somewhere in the solution, as requested in the problem description. Test your solution like this:

```
(partition 3 '(a b c d e f g h))
=> '((a b c) (d e f) (g h))

(partition 3 '(a b c d e f g h i))
=>'((a b c) (d e f) (g h i))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have filled in the blanks of it and i get
(cond ((empty? lst)
       lst
      ((< (length lst) n)
      lst)
        (else
        (cons (take lst n)
         (partition n (drop lst n))))))

but when I do (partition 3 '(a b c d e f g h)) I get 
((a b c) (d e f) g h) so its missing a parenthesis before the g and I was wondering what i did wrong so i could make it '((a b c) (d e f) (g h)) instead of (.... g h). Is my drop or take function written incorrectly thats causing that (had to write my own take & drop)

Comment: @user1869703 notice that in the second case you must return "a list with lst as its only element". In other words, this:  `(list lst)`